# example of a hilbert series

Tags: commutative-algebra

I know how to compute Hilbert series for the ordinary polynomial ring in $n$ variables. Consider now the following ring

$$
\mathbb{F}[x,y,z]/(xy^{3})
$$
where $(xy^{3})$ denote the ideal generated by $xy^{3}$ with the ordinary graduading, i.e. $deg(x) = deg(y) = deg(z) = 1$. Now for an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring $R$ = $\bigoplus\limits_{i\geq0}R_{i}$ over $\mathbb{F}$ where $R_{i}$ denotes the i-th homogeneous components of $R$, the hilbert series is defined as follows

$$
\text{Hilb}(R;t) := \sum_{i\geq0}\text{dim}_{\mathbb{F}}R_{i} \cdot t^{i}.
$$

My question is now, how the hilbert series does look like for the Special example above. I have to compute the Dimension of the $i$-th homogeneous components of $\mathbb{F}[x,y,z]/(xy^{3})$. Hope someone can help me

Comment: What is the dimension?

Comment: what are you mean?

Comment: What is the basis of $R_i?$

Comment: that is my Problem, how to compute $dim R_{i}$. If we look at the ring $\mathbb{F}[x,y,z]$ then $R_{i} = \text{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x^{a}y^{b}z^{c}:a + b + c = i\}$. In this case we have $dim R_{i}$ = $3 + i -1 \choose i$

Comment: Try describe  the basis for small $i$ - $R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4.$

Comment: but now $R_{i}$ is the $i$-th homogeneous component of the above Quotient ring and I don't know how to compute a Basis. For example I have $R_{2}$ the Basis $\{x^{2},y^{2},z^{2},xy,xz,yz\}$. So I have $\text{dim}R_{2} = 6$. Furthermore I have $\text{dim}R_{3} = 10$ and $\text{dim}R_{4} = 15$

Comment: Is there maybe a General result to compute the Hilbert series by knowing the hilbert series of $\mathbb{F}[x,y,z]$. The Hilbert series of $\mathbb{F}[x,y,z]$ is given by $\frac{1}{(1-t)^{3}}$